# Use linkdata to change number of histogram bins from a slider

Tags: histogram, uicontrol

I'm currently working on plotting a histogram that changes the number of bins as I use a slider. I have the histogram plotted along with a set number of bins saved to variable "nbins". I also have a uicontrol slider. How would I change the value of nbins as the slider value changes while updating my plot in real time? Thanks!